# Calculate .m4s segment file suffix in HTML5 video streaming when user seeks to another time

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash, media-source, mp4box

I have created fixed length segments for a long MP4 video using Mp4Box. Mp4Box creates a meta info file `mv_init.mp4` and segments like `mv_1.m4s`, `mv_2.m4s`, … I stream the video using HTML5 Media Source Extensions and the streaming is working properly.

The problem is that **I am unable to utilize time seeking feature of my HTML5 player**. When a user uses the seekbar to seek to another time point, I need to fetch the correct segment file (`mv_{number}.m4s`) for that `currentTime`.

For example:

- video duration: 2 hours
- segment size: 10 seconds
- user seeks to time: 25 minutes

25 minutes = 25 × 60 seconds = 1500 seconds. As each segment is of 10 seconds, I need segment number 1500 / 10 = 150. The needed segment file is `mv_150.m4s`.

The calculation apparently seems correct, but the HTML5 player then **downloads many more files after `mv_150.m4s` before it continues with the streaming**.

How to correctly calculate segment file number, so that after seeking, the streaming runs smoothly, without downloading any extra files?

To create the segments of the MP4 video, I used the following command:

```
MP4Box -dash 10000 -out video.mpd -dash-profile live -segment-name mv_ -rap video.mp4
```

Comment: Are you the author of the player? Can you please include a [mcve]? I.e. a minimal example demonstrating the problem. Which browser do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have researched on the matter and found the real cause. The caluclation for loading the segments was correct. The issue was with the key frame interval in video file. A keyframe is a frame in video from which the video can subsequently load and run from that point. So in my case I need to insert keyframe at the start of each segment. Therefore when we seek through the video in different time positions the next segment that is loaded contains a keyframe at the start of it.

The keyframes in video file can be setup using FFMPEG. So for example if we have a video having segments of 5 seconds then we must create keyframe at 5 seconds interval using ffmpeg. Another important point while setting up keyframes is to look into FRAME RATE of video. The video must have a fixed frame rate so we can precisely calculate the position of keyframe.

**Example:**

```
Video File: gladiator.mp4

Segment Size: 5 seconds
```

No we set FRAME RATE and KEY FRAME INTERVAL USING FFMPEG

> ffmpeg -i gladiator.mp4 -x264-params
>   keyint=120:min-keyint=120:no-scenecut=1 -r 24 gladiator-output.mp4

```
keyint=120 i.e; 24 fps * 5 seconds = 120
```

And now we create the segment files using Mp4Box

> MP4Box -dash 5000 -frag 5000 -out gladiator.mpd -dash-profile
>   on-demand -segment-name mv_ gladiator-output.mp4

So it will create segments like mv_1,mv_2, .. and so on having keyframes at the start of each segment file.

[Seekable Dash Streaming Example](http://asimishaq.com/files/dash-example/index.html)